# Bad Request/Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, twitter, wso2

I am using AngularJS, node.js, express.js, wso2 and Twitter API to communicate between Twitter and my application.
Coming to the problem, I am trying to send a message to Twitter from my application using wso2 to connect to Twitter and send the response.

Below is the XML which will send the message to the Twitter account and is posting successfully using Postman but the moment I try it in my application it is giving Bad Request/Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="tweetReply"
   startOnLoad="true"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   transports="http">
 <target>
  <inSequence>
     <property expression="json-eval($.screen_name)" name="screen_name"/>
     <property expression="json-eval($.text)" name="text"/>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="INIT" value="##### Subas - Call to the Proxy 
   #####"/>
     </log>
     <twitter.init>
        <consumerKey>some keyt</consumerKey>
        <consumerSecret>some secret</consumerSecret>
        <accessToken>access-token</accessToken>            
       `<accessTokenSecret>access-token-secret</accessTokenSecret>`
     </twitter.init>
     <twitter.sendNewDirectMessages>
        <screenName>{$ctx:screen_name}</screenName>
        <text>{$ctx:text}</text>
     </twitter.sendNewDirectMessages>
     <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
     <respond/>
    </inSequence>
   </target>
  <description/>
  </proxy>
```

When I generate the URL from the above XML it works fine, below is the URl which i am getting when we generate form the above XML

```
http://hostname:8280/services/tweetReply.tweetReplyHttpEndpoint
```

and the request payload will be :

```
{
 "screen_name":"pawan_mks",
 "text":"hello"
 }
```

and sends the message to Twitter but doing the same thing with AngularJS gives me problem

Here is the AngularJS code I am trying to use:

```
 $scope.sendReplyMsg = function(replyMessage) {
        var dataObj = {
            "screen_name": "pawan_mps",
            "text": "Hi Pawan From Angular JS"
        };    
        var headerObj = {


       headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization,Lang',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
           }
        };

$http.post("http://hostname:8280/services/tweetReply.tweetReplyHttpEndpoint", 
         dataObj, headerObj)
              .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {                  
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                 {
                   console.log(status);
                 })
          }
```

Comment: What is `http://u/`, is that supposed to be the twitter API endpoint? Why are you setting all those Access-Control headers in _your_ code? Have you checked what the response body contains when you get the 400 status code?

Comment: I have Updated the URL...It has something to do with Cross Domain and i am finding it pretty hard to configure it...

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually arrives when there's a problem with CORS configurations.

If you are testing this from local machine or another host which is different from the host in which your backend is served in you'll end up in Cross origin errors (CORS). Ask your backend developer to enable CORS in the backend, there's not much that you can do on the front end.

Explaining why this works on postman and not in chrome is because Chrome enforces CORS as browser side security, but not Postman.

Comment: So basically your saying that i need to do configuration changes on the WSO2 -Tool rather than on the Angular JS part...

Comment: Care to comment how'd do it?